# How to write multiple txt files with the condition that each sentence is separated after preprocessing as an independent txt file in python?

Tags: python, txt

After preprocessing the data, I was able to separate the content into separate sentences. However, I don't know how to write to a txt file, in which each txt file contains one sentence. I tried using a for loop but it didn't work. Help me

```
i = 0
for i in sentences:
    path = os.path.join("D:/codekpw/20_33_data2/pre-processing", f"{i:03d}.txt")
   
    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        
        f.write(str(i))
        i += 1
    print(f"created successfully {i} file txt.")
```

Comment: What do you expect `i` to be? a number or element of `sentences`? You can't have both, and that is what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're treating `i` as both a sentence and a number. Since it can't be both at the same time you need to use `enumerate` to get the index of the sentence as well as the sentence:

```py
import os

# Assuming 'sentences' is a list of sentences
sentences = ["This is the first sentence.", "This is the second sentence.", "And this is the third sentence."]

for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    path = os.path.join("D:/codekpw/20_33_data2/pre-processing", f"{i:03d}.txt")

    with open(path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(sentence)

    print(f"Created successfully {i} file txt.")
```